# Can I set the iOS Date picker default date to be blank?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uidatepicker

I am trying to set the iOS UIDatePicker to have a blank default date instead of the current date. is this possible?

Comment: What is the mode and style of the `UIDatePicker`? What would it show with a "blank" default? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: the style is compact. it defaults on load to the Current date, but I want the default date to be blank. the use case is the date is nullable, so if the user does not need to enter a date , there should not be a default.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. There is a `date` property for the initial date. If `nil` it defaults to "now". If you try to use something like `Date.distantPast` it actually sets the date to December 31, 1. That's year 1.

I suggest filing an enhancement request with Apple.

In the meantime you can use your own button next to a label. Have the button show a `UIDatePicker` with `preferredDateStype` set to `.inline`. With the right setup you can support having a "nullable" date. I do something similar in one of my apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pikerView like that:

Declare your array of months(or what you prefer), conform your controller to UIPickerViewDelegate an UIPickerViewDataSource:

```
class Prova: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

let months: [String] = [" " ,"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"] // months array

let pickerView = UIPickerView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = .white

    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self
    pickerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    //set constraints
    view.addSubview(pickerView)
    pickerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    pickerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    pickerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    pickerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return months.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return months[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
// do whatever you want when specific row is selected
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {

    let rowTitle = months[row]
    let pickerLabel = UILabel()

    pickerLabel.textColor = .black

    pickerLabel.text = rowTitle
    pickerLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16)
    pickerLabel.textAlignment = .center

    return pickerLabel
 }
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Note that the OP stated (in a comment below the question) that they are using the `UIDatePicker` in `.compact` style. This is what you see in the Calendar app for the start date and end date when adding a new calendar entry. No picker view is ever displayed. It uses the new calendar display when the field is tapped on.